# WeakReference leaking when using WeakEventManager

Tags: c#, weak-references

I am using WeakEventManager to weakly subscribe to events in short lived instances.

My code in the event subscribers is this:

```
    internal ShortLivedClass(IDataRecord record) : base()
    {
         WeakEventManager<CuentasDao, RemovedFromCacheEventArgs<int>>.AddHandler(Daos.Cuentas, "RemovedFromCache", (object sender, RemovedFromCacheEventArgs<int> e) => { if (_idCuenta == e.Id) { Cuenta = null; } });
    }
```

It works as expected, subscribed instances get garbage collected, but after a memory profile, I see a lot of "WeakReference" instances remains in memory that  doesn't get garbage collected.

[image: WeakReferences]

I thought about Removing the handler in the Disposing method, but that will make my code a lot more verbose because i will have to extract the handler to another method, and i intend to use this pattern all across my code.

Any suggestions?